# Photo of the week

Tags: discussion, photographer

I’m new to this site and wondering if is it any active photo of the week is ongoing right now. I want to submit a photo I took recently and don’t know where to share it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry to point you to a (closed) dupe question, but it's the direct question, same comments apply.